# How to show Auth0 Lock in an inline page container when using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I am using Auth0 Lock to authenticate users and I'm trying to have the Lock widget not as popup but embedded in the page itself.

I tried using the `container` option and calling the `lock.show()` method from a script in the page I want it to load but it doesn't. Only if I call the `lock.show()` method from inside a function within `ng-click` does it shows the widget.

Initializing the Lock widget:

```
lockProvider.init({
        clientID: 'XXX',
        domain: 'YYY.auth0.com',
        options: {
            allowSignUp: false,
            container: 'hiw-login-container',
            auth: {
                responseType: 'token',
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid email'
                }
            },
            allowedConnections: ['Username-Password-Authentication']
        }
    });
```

The view:

```html
 <div ng-if="!isAuthenticated" >
   <script>
       lock.show();
    </script>
    <md-content>
        <div id="hiw-login-container" style="width: 320px; margin: 40px auto; padding: 10px; border-style: dashed; border-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box;">
             embedded area
         </div>
     </md-content>
 </div>
```

Calling `lock.show` from `ng-click`:

```html
<md-button class="md-warn md-raised"
           aria-label="Login"
           ng-click="toolbar.authService.login()"
           ng-if="!isAuthenticated">
  Login
</md-button>

function login() {
    lock.show();
}
```

I can't upload pictures so here are links to the results shown when running the app:

1. Initial state - before pressing anything ([HomePage before pressing the login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LV0p.jpg))
2. After pressing the login button ([HomePage after pressing login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LLun.jpg))

Why doesn't it show the widget from the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Angular so any Javascript code that is dependent of its rendering pipeline because it uses HTML elements that are managed by Angular itself need to play by those rules.

When you call it from `ng-click` Angular already did its thing and Lock will correctly find the target element and display correctly.

When you try to call `lock.show` from an inline script you can't guarantee that Angular already completed processing and things won't work.

You need to call `lock.show` from code that is Angular aware; you could consider a few things:

```
function YourController($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', lock.show);
}
```

or

```
angular.element(lock.show);
```

or even consider going for a directive that understands when Angular has made the HTML element available and calls `lock.show`.

Comment: thank you very much! works great, and your explanation was very clear :)

Comment: i am encountering a new issue - Can't find element with id hiw-login-container
    at ContainerManager.ensure (https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.6/lock.js:39667:14), it works for login but if i do logout it doesnt show the container anymore -

Comment: In the original code you're placing the `hiw-login-container` element within a conditional `if` that means the container is only rendered when the user is not authenticated. Can this be the cause?

Comment: maybe, ive tried having a different route for the login so there is no condition on the div but it stops working all together i dont know why.